# How to disable Picture in Picture mode for default video player

Tags: ios, swift, ios9, avkit

How can I disable Picture in Picture button/mode using Swift in iOS9 on iPad when user tries to play a video in my app?

Comment: What "default video player" are you using?

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. My application runs within WKWebView and I'm referring to "default video player" as to the player that is being opened by WKWebView

Comment: That info belongs in the question. [edit]

Comment: If it's in WKWebView, I guess you need https://stackoverflow.com/a/54469523/276648

Answer (score 9):

Default AVPlayerLayers won't use PiP unless you use an [AVPictureInPictureController](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/AVKit/Reference/AVPictureInPictureController_Class/index.html).

AVPlayerViewController has a property [`allowsPictureInPicture`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVPlayerViewController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/AVPlayerViewController/allowsPictureInPicturePlayback) which you can set to `false`.

Answer (score 0):

In iOS 16.4, You can hide **picture-in-picture** button by using below code:

We have `AVPlayerViewController` which has property `allowsPictureInPicturePlayback` and we can set it false so that the PIP Button will not show.

```
self.allowsPictureInPicturePlayback = false
```