# How to disable Picture in Picture mode on HTML5 video

Tags: html5-video

How do you disable **Picture in Picture** mode on html5 videos?

> Please note I'm not referring to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32726385/how-to-disable-picture-in-picture-mode-for-default-video-player) which relates to
>   Apple's AVKit

I know you can disable video download with `controlsList="nodownload"`, how is it possible for **Picture in Picture** mode.

```html
<video controls controlsList="nodownload">
  <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.ogg" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/ogg">
</video>
```

Answer (score 78, accepted):

per the spec at https://wicg.github.io/picture-in-picture/#disable-pip,
the attribute to control this is `disablePictureInPicture`

```
<video controls disablePictureInPicture controlsList="nodownload">
  <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.ogg" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/ogg">
</video>
```

to achieve the same through javascript:

```
<video id="vid" controls muted>
<source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4">
</video>
<script>
vid=document.getElementById("vid")
vid.disablePictureInPicture = true
</script>
```

Comment: @m93a same with 76 on macOS. Guess there's a bug that needs reporting...

Comment: I don't think `kitsune` is the right place to report this. [Bugzilla](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1545554) is the place to report Firefox bugs.

Comment: yeah, I realised after I did it! feel free to report it

Comment: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1611831 Mozilla considers not following the spec is a feature.

Comment: Works for Opera's annoying pop-out feature too!

Comment: Seems like this toggle does nothing fore Firefox 102.0.

Comment: as per comment above, Mozilla deliberately decided to ignore the spec for this. I guess more comments/feedback on the bug might help get it re-visited https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1611831

Comment: @Offbeatmammal comment 35 of bug 1611831 gives a clue on how one might be able to disable picture-in-picture, as long as Mozilla doesn't change its position, and as long as one is willing to get the same part of the video covered by some other icon:
"Firefox does make an effort to not trigger Picture-in-Picture when the user clicks on a surface that's overlaid on top of the toggle that is sufficiently opaque". (see [here](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/page.cgi?id=comment-revisions.html&bug_id=1611831&comment_id=15398968))

Comment: @Offbeatmammal ah sorry, it seems that I missed that since FF 116, the disabling is respected by FF at least to some extent: PiP icon is not shown and if the user nevertheless tries to enable PiP (e.g. via right-clik), one is getting a warning. So I think it's ok now...

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do it through JavaScript.
This code applies for all videos on your page and it disables the download,take picture and right click context which also contains download option.

You may want to change `jQuery` to `$`
I wrote this code add it to my theme in WordPress to disable the download in all videos in my site.

```
jQuery('video').on("loadeddata", function() {
    jQuery('video').attr('controlsList', 'nodownload');
    jQuery('video').bind('contextmenu',function() { return false; });
    jQuery('video').attr('disablePictureInPicture', 'true');
});
```

**Notes:**

1- you are applying the attributes and binding the function to all `<video>` elements of the page for each of them which triggers the loadeddata event. You must replace `jQuery('video')` with `jQuery(this)` inside the `loadeddata` event handler.

2- `disablePictureInPicture` is supported by most of the browsers but not all of them
[image: disablePictureInPicture]
It can get more support by time.

Comment: Note that you are applying the attributes and binding the function to **all <video> elements of the page** for each of them which triggers the `loadeddata` event. You must replace `jQuery('video')` with `jQuery(this)` inside the `loadeddata` event handler.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```html
<video controls disablePictureInPicture>
```

The `disablePictureInPicture` is a boolean flag that would disable picture in picture item in three dots menu.